# compare dicts and combine keys/values

Tags: loops, dictionary, ansible

I have a list of dicts containing servernames and server Id's

```
"servers": [
    {
        "servername": "server1.example.com",
        "server_id": "1111-bbbb"
    },
    {
        "servername": "server2.example.com",
        "server_id": "2222-bbbb"
    },
    {
        "servername": "server3.example.com",
        "server_id": "3333-cccc"
    },
    {
        "servername": "server4.example.com",
        "server_id": "4444-aaaa"
    }
]
```

A separate dict contains cluster names and, the member server ID's

```
"clusters": {
    "cluster1": [
        "1111-bbbb",
        "3333-cccc"
    ],
    "cluster2": [
        "2222-bbbb",
        "4444-aaaa"
    ]
}
```

I need to loop through both using the Server IDs and add the Cluster Name to the Servers list

```
"servers": [
    {
        "servername": "server1.example.com",
        "server_id": "1111-bbbb",
        "cluster": "cluster1"
    },
    {
        "servername": "server2.example.com",
        "server_id": "2222-bbbb",
        "cluster": "cluster2"
    },
    {
        "servername": "server3.example.com",
        "server_id": "3333-cccc",
        "cluster": "cluster1"
    },
    {
        "servername": "server4.example.com",
        "server_id": "4444-aaaa",
        "cluster": "cluster2"
    }
]
```

I've tried the following

```
- name: Add Cluster name to servers
  set_fact:
    something: "{{ servers + [{ 'cluster': item.key }] }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.dict', clusters) }}"
  when: servers.server_id in item.value
```

This returns the error **'list object' has no attribute 'server_id'**
I think that i need to also loop through servers but, have been unable to loop_control (loop_var) to work

I've also tried

```
- name: add Cluster name to servers
  set_fact:
    merged: |
      {% for e in servers %}
      {% for key, value in e.items() %}
      {% for k, v in clusters %}
      {% if value['server_id'] in v %}
      {{e + [{'cluster': k}]}}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

This also returns an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the dictionary

```yaml
  id_cluster_str: |
    {% for k,v in clusters.items() %}
    {% for i in v %}
    {{ i }}: {{ k }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  id_cluster: "{{ id_cluster_str|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  id_cluster:
    1111-bbbb: cluster1
    2222-bbbb: cluster2
    3333-cccc: cluster1
    4444-aaaa: cluster2
```

Get the list of *server_id*, extract the corresponding *cluster*, and create the list of dictionaries

```yaml
  cluster: "{{ servers|map(attribute='server_id')|
                       map('extract', id_cluster)|
                       map('community.general.dict_kv', 'cluster') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  cluster:
  - cluster: cluster1
  - cluster: cluster2
  - cluster: cluster1
  - cluster: cluster2
```

Combine the items on the lists and update the list *servers*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        servers: "{{ servers|zip(cluster)|map('combine') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  servers:
  - cluster: cluster1
    server_id: 1111-bbbb
    servername: server1.example.com
  - cluster: cluster2
    server_id: 2222-bbbb
    servername: server2.example.com
  - cluster: cluster1
    server_id: 3333-cccc
    servername: server3.example.com
  - cluster: cluster2
    server_id: 4444-aaaa
    servername: server4.example.com
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    servers:
      - server_id: 1111-bbbb
        servername: server1.example.com
      - server_id: 2222-bbbb
        servername: server2.example.com
      - server_id: 3333-cccc
        servername: server3.example.com
      - server_id: 4444-aaaa
        servername: server4.example.com

    clusters:
      cluster1: [1111-bbbb, 3333-cccc]
      cluster2: [2222-bbbb, 4444-aaaa]

    id_cluster_str: |
      {% for k,v in clusters.items() %}
      {% for i in v %}
      {{ i }}: {{ k }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    id_cluster: "{{ id_cluster_str|from_yaml }}"

    cluster: "{{ servers|map(attribute='server_id')|
                         map('extract', id_cluster)|
                         map('community.general.dict_kv', 'cluster') }}"
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: id_cluster
    - debug:
        var: cluster

    - set_fact:
        servers: "{{ servers|zip(cluster)|map('combine') }}"
    - debug:
        var: servers
```